# Cannot run iOS Keyboard Extension on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

Previously I've been able to run and debug a custom keyboard extension on my personal device by selecting the appropriate scheme, selecting the Messages app (`MobileSMS.app`) executable to run in, and then opening a conversation.

However lately whenever I attempt to run the Messages app, Xcode will automatically terminate with the message **Finished running MobileSMS.app on iPhone**. The app will launch on my device, but the session is completed and therefore I'm unable to debug the keyboard app.

It still works fine on the Simulator.

Does anyone have any experience with the same issue? Any ideas how I can go about troubleshooting it?

Comment: Does it still happen if you use a text view in your keyboard extension's app?

Comment: @MichaelHulet Unfortunately yes, it goes straight from _"Running xyz.app on iPhone"_ to _"Finished running xyz.app on iPhone"_